# how to get single array of comma seperate value from array

Tags: php, arrays

this is my array i want to process.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [checklist_id] => 3 [order_id] => [id] => 1 )
>   [1] => Array ( [checklist_id] => 4 [order_id] => [id] => 2 ) [2] =>
>   Array ( [checklist_id] => 7 [order_id] => 8,9,10,11,12 [id] => 4 ) );

after trying `array_push`

```
$alreadyassingorder=array();
        foreach ($collection as  $checklistorder) {
            if($checklistorder['order_id'])
            {
             $order=explode(',', $checklistorder['order_id']);

             array_push($alreadyassingorder,$order);

            }
        }
```

**the output is**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5
>   [5] => 6 [6] => 7 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 [3] =>
>   11 [4] => 12 ) )

**the output i want**

> Array (  [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5
>   [5] => 6 [6] => 7 )  [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 [10] =>
>   11 [11] => 12 ) )

Comment: Use `array_merge` instead of `array_push`

Comment: @u_mulder did that but not getting the required output

Comment: did you try loop with array_push? i mean `foreach($order as $index=>$key) array_push($alreadyassingorder,$key);` ?

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar thanks it worked kindly post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$alreadyassingorder=array();
        foreach ($collection as  $checklistorder) {
            if($checklistorder['order_id'])
            {
             $order=explode(',', $checklistorder['order_id']);
             foreach($order as $index=>$key):     
               array_push($alreadyassingorder,$key);
             endforeach;

            }
        }
```